# How do I Get Text from Dynamically created element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I am dynamically creating Div Text in JS and was wondering how I access the various text upon click.

Here is what I have tried so far;

**My Dynamically created div**

```
function Message(Side, message) {

var divChat = '<div class="direct-chat-msg ' + Side + '">' +
                  '<div id="myDiv" class="direct-chat-text">' + message + '</div>' +

                    '<div id="accountMenu">' +
                    '<li onclick = "getMessage(' + message + ')" id="replyDiv">Reply</li>' +
                    '<li>Preferences</li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                    '</div></div>';

    $('#divChatWindow').append(divChat);

}
```

**JS when the *li* is clicked on.**

```
 function getMessage(str) {
     alert(str);
 }
```

**The error I am getting is:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: *whaeverthemessageis* is not defined
    at HTMLLIElement.onclick
```

What is the best solution to solve this problem?

Thanks =)

Comment: The variable “message” is not defined.

Comment: ive updated my code @PeterKA, please check

Comment: Can you please set up a snippet to demo the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have malformed html using single and double quotes. The message is being treated as a variable, not a string, hence the undefined error.

replace:

```
'<li onclick = "getMessage(' + message + ')" id="replyDiv">Reply</li>' +
```

with this:

```
'<li onclick = "getMessage(\'' + message + '\')" id="replyDiv">Reply</li>' +
```

Comment: Just tried that, I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: The parameter sent to Message function is 'side' but you are trying to access it using 'Side'. Javascript is case sensitive. There is no syntax error in the code I posted.

Comment: Please ignore that. I made a mistake when writing the code on stackoverflow.

Comment: Apologies. So It works now, but only sometimes which is weird. When the Side is me, it works but when the Side is someone else, it shows that exception weirdly. **Might be out of context but I am using Signal R**

Comment: I am not sure what is the value of Side in your code, as we cannot see that. maybe there are special characters in the string. But the value of side have nothing to do with what was asked in the question. To test, you can remove the Side in class from the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, but here is a working [Playcode](https://playcode.io/468642?tabs=script.js,preview)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Your answer isn't really good enough. SO's main purpose is to collect & store valuable questions and answers for other visitors to use _ Using a link to a possible answer might not be useful later on if the link target is deleted. If you aren't "_exactly sure what the problem is _" then it would probably be best not to answer at all BUT please remember to add code to your answer whenever possible _ Thanks